# QuickSort on a String

Tags: java, sorting

I'm implementing the quicksort algorithm to a pair of strings to check if one is a permutation of another and I'm running into this error with the sorting code:

```
public class IsPermutation{
   public static void main(String[] args){
  String str1 = "abc";
  String str2 = "cba";
  System.out.println(checkPermutation2(str1,str2));
}

public static boolean checkPermutation2(String str1, String str2){
   if(str1.length() != str2.length()) return false;
   sort(str1,0,str1.length() - 1);
   sort(str2,0,str2.length()-1);
   for(int i = 0; i < str2.length();i++){
     for(int j = 0; j < str1.length();j++){
        if(str2.charAt(i) == str1.charAt(j)) continue;
        else return false;

     }
  }
  return true;
}

public static void sort(String str, int low, int high){
   if(low < high){
      int pi = partition(str,low,high);
      sort(str,low,pi-1);
      sort(str,pi+1,high);
   }
}
public static int partition(String str, int low, int high){
   int pivot = str.charAt(high);
   int i = low - 1;
   for(int j = low; j<high-1;j++){
      if(str.charAt(j) <= pivot){
         i++;
         swap(str,i,j);
      }
   }
   swap(str,(i+1),(high));
}

public static void swap(String str,int from, int to){
   char temp = str.charAt(from);
   str.charAt(from) = str.charAt(to);
   str.charAt(to) = temp;
}
```

I'm getting this error, how do I fix it?

[image: Unexpected Type]

Comment: Please replace the link to the picture of error message with the actual text.

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: If you mean to sort the *characters* in a `String`, then you cannot, because strings are immutable. You can however call [`toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--), sort the `char[]` using [`Arrays.sort(arr)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-char:A-), then create a string with the sorted characters using [`new String(arr)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-char:A-). Or skip the last step and simply compare the `char[]` values directly.

Comment: @Andreas that looks like an answer, no?

Comment: @JimGarrison Good point. Expanded upon it a bit too.

Comment: @Andreas "expanded ... a bit" is rather an understatement :-) You got my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you mean to sort the *characters* in a `String`, but you cannot do that, because strings are immutable.

You can however call [`toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--), sort the `char[]` using [`Arrays.sort(arr)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-char:A-), then create a string with the sorted characters using new [`String(arr)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-char:A-).

Or skip the last step and simply compare the `char[]` values directly.

Also note that the double `for` loop in `checkPermutation2` doesn't work. You just need to check if the two strings are now the same.

```
public static boolean checkPermutation2(String str1, String str2) {
    char[] arr1 = str1.toCharArray();
    char[] arr2 = str2.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(arr1);
    Arrays.sort(arr2);
    return Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2);
}
```

---

**A bit of fun**

Your method is almost the same as an [anagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram) checker, except that anagrams only check letters and are case-insensitive.

A little re-work can fix that, i.e. get rid of all non-letters<sup>1</sup> and convert to lowercase before comparing:

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String str1, String str2) {
    char[] arr1 = str1.replaceAll("\\P{L}+", "").toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char[] arr2 = str2.replaceAll("\\P{L}+", "").toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(arr1);
    Arrays.sort(arr2);
    return Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2);
}
```

<sup>1) Regex `\P{L}` match any character *except* one in Unicode category "letter".</sup>

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("foo", "bar");
    test("abc", "cba");
    test("silent", "listen");
    test("funeral", "real fun");
    test("funeral", "realfun");
    test("Dormitory", "Dirty Room");
    test("To be or not to be: that is the question; whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer the slings and arrows of outrageous fortune...",
         "In one of the Bard's best-thought-of tragedies our insistent hero, Hamlet, queries on two fronts about how life turns rotten.");
}
public static void test(String str1, String str2) {
    System.out.printf("Permutation = %-5s  Anagram = %-5s  \"%s\" vs \"%s\"%n",
                      checkPermutation2(str1, str2), isAnagram(str1, str2), str1, str2);
}
```

*Output*

```
Permutation = false  Anagram = false  "foo" vs "bar"
Permutation = true   Anagram = true   "abc" vs "cba"
Permutation = true   Anagram = true   "silent" vs "listen"
Permutation = false  Anagram = true   "funeral" vs "real fun"
Permutation = true   Anagram = true   "funeral" vs "realfun"
Permutation = false  Anagram = true   "Dormitory" vs "Dirty Room"
Permutation = false  Anagram = true   "To be or not to be: that is the question; whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer the slings and arrows of outrageous fortune..." vs "In one of the Bard's best-thought-of tragedies our insistent hero, Hamlet, queries on two fronts about how life turns rotten."
```